# Understanding the exact action of the With keyword in VBA - unexpected behavior

Tags: vba, excel

To refactor and optimize some vba code, I started replacing series of statements that were repeatedly refering to a single object using `with`.

At first I thought that

```
Object.operation1()
Object.operation2()
```

was equivalent to

```
With Object
    .operation1()
    .operation2()
End With
```

and that the difference was that the second solution was just faster because we were referring to the object only once.

**Then** I ran on the following case:

Il have a sheet that is filled line by line, using `.End(xlDown)` to find the last free line, and the cells are accessed thanks to  `Offset(params)`:

*Case 1*

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = aValue
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1) = anOtherValue
```

*Result*:

```
 XXX           XXX           XXX             <- Old line
 aValue        anOtherValue                  <- New line
```

which is **not** equivalent to

*Case 2*

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown)
    .Offset(1, 0) = aValue
    .Offset(0, 1) = anOtherValue
End With
```

*Result*:

```
 XXX           anOtherValue  XXX
 aValue
```

**but** is equivalent to

*Case 3*

```
With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").End(xlDown)
    .Offset(1, 0) = aValue
    .Offset(1, 1) = anOtherValue
End With
```

*Result*:

```
 XXX           XXX           XXX
 aValue        anOtherValue
```

*NOTE: by "equivalent" I mean "with the same result"*

I imagine that with `With` the values are set then the sheet is updated, that's why with the **second case** the second `Offset()` considers that no new cells have been filled in the sheet (that's why `anOtherValue` is at the end not in the right cell, because when `Offset(0,1)` is called the cell which is supposed to contain `aValue` is empty).
Hoping this is clear ...

So (finally) my question is:

Does anyone knows how `With` exacty work/behave? because I didn't found any clear description on the web. I understand that it's referring to the object only once, but does it means it doesn't undate the object during the process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`With` simply obtains and holds a reference to the specified object. That reference doesn't change. (you can think of it as being an implicit variable)

Your `end(xlDown)` code doesn't refer to the same range the second time, for obvious reasons, so it's not equivalent to your With block.

Assume you have A1 selected, and run this code:

```
Sub foo()
    With ActiveCell
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
        MsgBox .Address
    End With
End Sub
```

even though the active cell is now A2, you will get A1 in the message because that was the active cell at the time the `With` line was run.

Equally, if you select A1 and run this:

```
Sub bar()
    With ActiveCell
        ActiveCell.Cut ActiveCell.Offset(1)
        MsgBox .Address
    End With
End Sub
```

you will see A2 in the message even though the active cell is still A1, because the cell referred to by the `With` block was moved. Note that if you copied it, instead of cutting, the message would show you A1 because that cell was not moved.

Comment: Thanks, that was roughly what I thought, but I was unable to find a place where it was explained clearly.

Comment: P.104 of the VBA language specification. :)

Comment: Sharp as always Rory!